# Codeigniter: Avoid browser caching during cross-controller redirection

Tags: php, caching, header, codeigniter-2

I was trying to avoid browser cache in my Codeigniter project. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4781814/1007378) answer very helpful. I was setting output header by the following code in my controller:

```
    $this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
$this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

It works fine for most of the cases. But when I redirect to a controller method of some other controller class, this process is not working. What should I do to set no-cache header during redirect to some other controller?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. When redirecting to some other controller, setting output header by $this reference is not correct. Because by setting header with $this reference only affect the output class of that controller.

To avoid caching cross-controller caching, you have to set header like this:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

You can also set header from the target class of redirection. But to avoid caching form submissions, the above process is fine.